# Adding an exiting VBA macro to a word document in python

Tags: python, linux, vba, ms-word

I need to generate a script that takes an exiting word document and a VBA macro in a text file, and would output the word document with the VBA macro embedded to it.

The script needs to be executed on a linux machine (ubuntu).
The use needs to be something like:

```python
InsertMacro.py -f mydoc.docx -m macro.txt -o mydoc_macro.docx
```

The *macro.txt* should looks something like:

```vb
Private Sub Auto_Open()
    MsgBox "This code runs when the document is opened!"
End Sub
```

During my research online, I have only found ways to do so on windows (import win32com or comtypes), but not on linux.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The only way to do this directly requires automating the Word & VB IDE interfaces. By default, this is blocked by security, so it would require the user (or network admin) de-blocking. If trying to add it via Office Open XML the VBA cannot be in plain text as VBA is in the old binary. In addition, macros added to docx will lock the file - it can't be opened in Word. This, too, is a security measure. The file type would have to be changed to docm.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I don't mind to change it to docm, the question remains the same about how to do it in python.

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer :-) And that's why it's posted as a comment - I'm aware that it's not an answer, just pointing out potential obstacles. I don't know whether Office applications can run on Linux - I think not, but I don't know. If they can't, then you need to leverage the Word Open XML file format.

Comment: If that's the case, besides changing to docm the macro would *have* to be in the Microsoft binary encoding - it cannot be plain text. The only way I've ever found to do something like this is to *export* the entire code *module* from the VBA editor (-> bas file) then incorporate that into the ZIP package, with the necessary rels entries. Non-trivial, but it can be worked out by using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool.